# Change the date format in kibana

Tags: date, elasticsearch, timestamp, kibana

I am working for my internship on the implementation of the ElasticSearch family (ElasticSearch+ Kibana+ logstash). Here is my question: I have a field "@ timestamp" with the following format: 2014-05-23T14: 56:18.055 Z. I would like to extract only the time ( hh:mm) and display it in a "table" in Kibana. I would also extract only the date in the format YYYY-MM-dd. I saw that it was possible in the case of a "Histogram" (always in Kibana) there is an option to change the format of the date, I tried to modify a little bit the file “module.js” but I still don’t get any solution. .

Could anyone help me Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this. You need to set "dynamic_date_formats" to your root object mapping.
Check out [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) post. I tried this using the .NET client NEST (which is 1 level above the native implementation) and it worked, so it will definitely work if you are using the native implementation.